# Getting "error: package android.view does not exist" error while migrating my existing Android Project from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java, android, java-11

I am wotking on multi-module Android project, currently this project is using Java 8 and as part of requirement I am upgrading this project to Java 11. Below is what I tried so far to achive the same-

1] Installed JDK-11 and set JDK location pointing to java-11 (i.e. File --> Project Structure --> SDK Location --> JDK Location)

2] As it is multi-module project, I did below chages in all module-level build.gradle files-

```
android{
       ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    } 
}
```

Then I am able to Sync and Build the project successfully, but when I'm trying to run the project, I'm getting "error: package android.view does not exist" error and some other related errors, please check below screenshot for more details--

[image]

I goolged this error and found couple of related posts on Stackoverflow (below are the links) but haven't found any concrete solution yet.

1] [error: package android.view does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542665/error-package-android-view-does-not-exist)

2] [Migrating Java 8 project to Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166816/migrating-java-8-project-to-java-11)

3] [android + sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11: error: package android.os does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551892/android-sourcecompatibility-javaversion-version-11-error-package-android-os)

- Important: I am using Android-Studio Version 4.1.2 and MacBook with macOS Big Sur

Also, please let me know in-case any other details required. Thank you!

Comment: what is your gradle-jdk version? 
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Select your gradle project.

Answer (score 2):

It was solved by changing the android gradle plugin version to 7.0.2.